# How to insert the CSV values into postgresdatabase

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el

i have done this configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:jdbc-ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/jdbc" xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.4.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/jdbc http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/jdbc/current/mule-jdbc-ee.xsd">
<configuration doc:name="Configuration">
    <expression-language autoResolveVariables="true">
        <import class="org.mule.util.StringUtils" />
        <import class="org.mule.util.ArrayUtils" />
    </expression-language>
</configuration>

    <jdbc-ee:postgresql-data-source name="PostgreSQL_Data_Source" user="youtilitydba" password="Youtility11" url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sample" transactionIsolation="UNSPECIFIED" doc:name="PostgreSQL Data Source"/>
    <jdbc-ee:connector name="Database" dataSource-ref="PostgreSQL_Data_Source" validateConnections="true" queryTimeout="-1" pollingFrequency="0" doc:name="Database"/>
    <flow name="CSVtoDATABASEFlow" doc:name="CSVtoDATABASEFlow">
        <file:inbound-endpoint path="/home/youtility2/Desktop/ESB/infile" moveToDirectory="/home/youtility2/Desktop/ESB/out" pollingFrequency="100" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File">
            <file:filename-regex-filter pattern="data.csv" caseSensitive="false"/>
        </file:inbound-endpoint>
        <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
        <logger message="before split ***************** #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <splitter expression="#[rows=StringUtils.split(message.payload, '\n\r');ArrayUtils.subarray(rows,1,rows.size())]" doc:name="Splitter"/>
        <logger message="after split ******************* #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <logger message="before db  ***********************   #[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" queryKey="insert" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="Database" doc:name="Database">
            <jdbc-ee:query key="insert" value="insert into users(firstname,lastname) values(#[message.payload],#[message.payload])"/>
        </jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

but inserted null values and only first letter of the value how can i achive to insert my wish value into db
csv files is like this with 2 cloumns
firstname lastname
ff            kk
dd            gg

and i logged my picking is well but unable to process into db even its spiting by row
some issue is der while inserting as value
my log

```
INFO  2013-11-29 16:53:33,110 [[csvtodatabase].CSVtoDATABASEFlow.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: before split ***************** firstname lastname
suresh  chirra
prasahnt    daware
anil    kancheti

INFO  2013-11-29 16:53:33,126 [[csvtodatabase].CSVtoDATABASEFlow.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: after split ******************* suresh   chirra
INFO  2013-11-29 16:53:33,130 [[csvtodatabase].CSVtoDATABASEFlow.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: before db  ***********************   suresh  chirra
INFO  2013-11-29 16:53:33,134 [[csvtodatabase].Database.dispatcher.01] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising: 'Database.dispatcher.2022023948'. Object is: EEJdbcMessageDispatcher
INFO  2013-11-29 16:53:33,135 [[csvtodatabase].Database.dispatcher.01] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Starting: 'Database.dispatcher.2022023948'. Object is: EEJdbcMessageDispatcher
INFO  2013-11-29 16:53:33,135 [[csvtodatabase].CSVtoDATABASEFlow.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: after split ******************* prasahnt daware
INFO  2013-11-29 16:53:33,137 [[csvtodatabase].CSVtoDATABASEFlow.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: before db  ***********************   prasahnt    daware
INFO  2013-11-29 16:53:33,139 [[csvtodatabase].Database.dispatcher.02] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising: 'Database.dispatcher.1701338672'. Object is: EEJdbcMessageDispatcher
INFO  2013-11-29 16:53:33,139 [[csvtodatabase].Database.dispatcher.02] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Starting: 'Database.dispatcher.1701338672'. Object is: EEJdbcMessageDispatcher
INFO  2013-11-29 16:53:33,143 [[csvtodatabase].CSVtoDATABASEFlow.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: after split ******************* anil kancheti
INFO  2013-11-29 16:53:33,149 [[csvtodatabase].CSVtoDATABASEFlow.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: before db  ***********************   anil    kancheti
INFO  2013-11-29 16:53:33,152 [[csvtodatabase].Database.dispatcher.03] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising: 'Database.dispatcher.660999458'. Object is: EEJdbcMessageDispatcher
INFO  2013-11-29 16:53:33,152 [[csvtodatabase].Database.dispatcher.03] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Starting: 'Database.dispatcher.660999458'. Object is: EEJdbcMessageDispatcher
INFO  2013-11-29 16:53:33,227 [[csvtodatabase].Database.dispatcher.02] com.mulesoft.mule.transport.jdbc.sqlstrategy.UpdateSqlStatementStrategy: Executing SQL statement: 1 row(s) updated
INFO  2013-11-29 16:53:33,227 [[csvtodatabase].Database.dispatcher.03] com.mulesoft.mule.transport.jdbc.sqlstrategy.UpdateSqlStatementStrategy: Executing SQL statement: 1 row(s) updated
INFO  2013-11-29 16:53:33,227 [[csvtodatabase].Database.dispatcher.01] com.mulesoft.mule.transport.jdbc.sqlstrategy.UpdateSqlStatementStrategy: Executing SQL statement: 1 row(s) updated
WARN  2013-11-29 17:51:30,468 [Finalizer] org.mule.transport.file.ReceiverFileInputStream: Failed to move file from /home/youtility2/Desktop/ESB/infile/data.csv to /home/youtility2/Desktop/ESB/out/data.cs
```

v
 my 3rd log is unable to print the value how could i achieve this
thanx a ton

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use

```
 <expression-transformer expression="#[StringUtils.split(message.payload, ',')]" />
```

and before using JDBC Component and use query as :- `insert into my_table(col1, col2) values(#[message.payload[0]],#[message.payload[1]])`

---

Anyway you can use the following flow and modify this according to your requirement... Here is your full XML Flow :-

```
  <configuration>
    <expression-language autoResolveVariables="true">
        <import class="org.mule.util.StringUtils" />
        <import class="org.mule.util.ArrayUtils" />
    </expression-language>
</configuration>

<spring:beans>
    <spring:bean id="jdbcDataSource" class=" ... your data source ... " />
</spring:beans>

<jdbc:connector name="jdbcConnector" dataSource-ref="jdbcDataSource">
    <jdbc:query key="insertRow"
        value="insert into my_table(col1, col2) values(#[message.payload[0]],#[message.payload[1]])" />
</jdbc:connector>

<flow name="csvFileToDatabase">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="/tmp/mule/inbox"
        pollingFrequency="5000" moveToDirectory="/tmp/mule/processed">
         <file:filename-wildcard-filter pattern="*.csv" />
    </file:inbound-endpoint>

    <!-- Load all file in RAM - won't work for big files! -->
    <file:file-to-string-transformer />
    <!-- Split each row, dropping the first one (header) -->
    <splitter
        expression="#[rows=StringUtils.split(message.payload, '\n\r');ArrayUtils.subarray(rows,1,rows.size())]" />
    <!-- Transform CSV row in array -->
    <expression-transformer expression="#[StringUtils.split(message.payload, ',')]" />
    <jdbc:outbound-endpoint queryKey="insertRow" />
</flow>
```